# requests.exception.ConnectionError in pymsteams code

Tags: python

Here is the code:

```
import pymsteams
myTeamsMessage = pymsteams.connectorcard("http://<NAME>")
myTeamsMessage.text("Hello how are you doing")
myTeamsMessage.send()
```

This is the error raised:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='%3cshreyas%20nair%3e', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001FB4B4DBD00>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))
```

Comment: i showed it it is below the error

Comment: First, you must make sure the url is accessible.  `ping url` to see if the url can be reach

Comment: and stackoverflow woudnt let me write the orignal code which is myTeamsMessage=pymsteamsconnectcard("http://<SHREYAS NAIR>")

Comment: th url is pinging  but this is a new error requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='%3chttps', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: //teams.microsoft.com/_?culture=en-in&country=IN&lm=deeplink&lmsrc=NeutralHomePageWeb&cmpid=WebSignIn (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x00000221B3DF1490>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))     now this error is happenign if

Comment: Those <angle brackets> are just place holders for you to substitute.  The `host` parameter needs to be a real, valid URL that you could type into a browser, and "<https" is not a real, valid URL.

Comment: if you have new information then better add it to question - it will be more readable and more people will see it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have proxies properly configured?

your system is running behind a proxy which is not allowing it. Try to set the settings of proxy to that of google's